# No entra en la sentencia if, aunque los datos coincidan

Tags: java

En el siguiente fragmento de código, espero que se imprima el texto dentro del `if` pero cuando lo ejecuto veo que no entra. He verificado que ambos objetos tienen los mismos datos para ser considerados iguales. ¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

```
public void maestrosColonia(Profesor [] profesores,String colonia){
    for(int i=0;i<profesores.length;i++) {
        if(colonia == profesores[i].getDireccion().getColonia()){
            System.out.println(profesores[i].getNombre()+" "+profesores[i].getNss()+" "+profesores[i].getTelefonos().getTelCasa());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa `equals` en lugar de `==`

```
if(colonia.equals(profesores[i].getDireccion().getColonia())){
```

O si es un String mejor usa `equalsIgnoreCase`

```
if(colonia.equalsIgnoreCase(profesores[i].getDireccion().getColonia())){
```